# Svg text element vertical flip

Tags: javascript, svg

I have problem with svg text element. I want to turn it over y axis.
For this, I using scale(-1,1) function.

```
var t = getMatrix(element);
t.scale(-1,1);
element.transform(t);
```

but element seems to be the same. Transformation does not work.

If I try to turn over horizontal axis, by scale(1,-1) function. It works

Please, What I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you put a test example on a jsfiddle ? Not sure what your getMatrix etc is.

Comment: You seem to be using a custom library, but without telling us what it is we can't help you out.  The answer below uses plain Javascript and the [W3 SVG interface methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransformList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I forgot to say that I use the library Snap svg.
It was bug there.

If someone will have the same problem, there is solution:
https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/153

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create transforms on an element in svg using the transform object, it is a five(5) step process:

1.) Attach the transform to your element.

```
var attachTransObject=myElement.transform
```

2.) Make a transform list for that attached transform.

```
var transObjList=attachTransObject.baseVal
```

3.) Start a Transform request object.

```
var requestTransformObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
```

4.) Perform/request the desired transform.

```
requestTransformObj.setScale(-1,1)
```

5.) Append the request to the transform list for the element.

```
transObjList.appendItem(requestTransformObj)
```

This may seem a bit obtuse, but once you understand these five steps, it is quite seamless.

For example, to flip a text element around the y axis, at  its x,y point would be as follows:

```
var x=parseFloat(myText.getAttribute("x"))
var y=parseFloat(myText.getAttribute("y"))

var attachTransObject=myText.transform
var transObjList=attachTransObject.baseVal
var requestTransformObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
requestTransformObj.setTranslate(x,y)
transObjList.appendItem(requestTransformObj)
var requestTransformObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
requestTransformObj.setScale(-1,1)
transObjList.appendItem(requestTransformObj)
var requestTransformObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
requestTransformObj.setTranslate(-x,-y)
transObjList.appendItem(requestTransformObj)
```

This would build a transformation on the text element similar to:

```
transform="translate(153.785 94.71) scale(-1 1) translate(-153.785 -94.71)"
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a language thing, but you confused me with "attach the transform to your element" and "Make a transform list".  The tranformation list already exists on the element, you are just saving it to a variable for easy access.

Comment: P.S. For the original poster, a simple working example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/LvuS3/.  Note that in the fiddle, the text is initially positioned with a transform, so I can just add in the negative scale factor as an additional transform in the list.  If the text had been positioned with x and y values, then you would need to adjust for them as in @Francis Hemsher's code (otherwise your content would be reflected outside of your svg boundaries).